# Pick a column for each row by column-header name

Tags: python, functional-programming, comparative-review

I am parsing a table:

> ```
>     |-------|
>     |Bar|Foo|
>     |-------|
>     | 5 | 6 |
>     |'f'|'g'|
>     | 1 | 8 |
>     |_______|
> ```

I've tried a number of ways of writing a `pick` function in Python:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

from collections import OrderedDict


def pick0(r, k):
    Bar, Foo = r
    return locals().get(k)


def pick1(r, k, h):
    try:
        return r[h.index(k)]
    except ValueError:
        return None


pick2 = lambda r, k, h: OrderedDict(zip(h, r)).get(k)

pick3 = lambda r, ks, h: map(lambda t: t[0] in ks and t[1] or None,
                             OrderedDict(zip(h, r)).iteritems())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    key = 'Foo'
    headers = 'Bar', 'Foo'
    for row in ((5, 6), ('f', 'g'), (1, 8)):
        # Method 0
        print OrderedDict(Bar=row[0], Foo=row[1]).get(key)

        # Method 1
        print pick0(row, key)

        # Method 2
        print pick1(row, key, headers)

        # Method 3
        print pick2(row, key, headers)

        # Method 4
        print pick3(row, ('Foo', 'Bar'), headers)
```

The last three methods are generalised. The last method allows you to specify multiple keys to pick out.

Comment: Where do the data come from? Are they from a CSV file, by any chance?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Answer (score 1):

The downside of all the functions, except `pick0`, is that the caller needs to know all the columns and their order. `pick0` is even worse as it is not reusable.

I would rather implement something similar to [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) that would give me each row as a `dict`, or perhaps as a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields)

If the usage is as simple as in the given example, one could also simply do this:

```
key_index = headers.index(key)
for row in ((5, 6), ('f', 'g'), (1, 8)):
    print row[key_index]
```

Other comments:

- Using `locals()` in `pick0` is dubious. A caller trying to pick `k` or `r` would get unexpected results.
- `lambda` is for creating nameless functions. Use `def` when you want to assign a name.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you stated in the comments that your data come from a CSV file, I recommend using the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module instead of any of these options.

```
import csv

with open(filename) as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print row['Foo']
```

`DictReader` produces a `dict` rather than an `OrderedDict`; use `reader.fieldnames` to discover the original order.

Using the `csv` module not only reduces the code for you to maintain, it also makes it easier for other programmers to understand your code.